# Why is "Featured Questions" Empty?

Tags: discussion

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured
is empty. What or who is supposed to populate the Featured Questions list?

If it's not being populated, can the tab be removed?

Answer (score 4):

Featured questions are questions that have a reputation bounty placed on them. The best answer is then awarded this bounty.

However, there are no questions currently with a bounty on them so no questions appear there.

Comment: @Marjorie Roswell makes a good point; it looks bad to have a tab with no *"feature questions"* so if there are none it would be nice if StackExchange removed the tab. Of course, unless they do, this comment is moot...